# How to replace particular characters of a string with the elements of a list in an efficient way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a string:

`input_str = 'The substring of "python" from index @ to index @ inclusive is "tho"'`

and a list of indices:

`idx_list = [2, 4]`

I want to replace the character `@` in `str_input` with each element of the `idx_list` to have the following output:

`output_str = 'The substring of "python" from index 2 to index 4 inclusive is "tho"'`

So I have coded it as follows:

```
def replace_char(input_str, idx_list):
    output_str = ""
    idx = 0
    for i in range(0, len(input_str)):
        if input_str[i] == '@':
            output_str += str(idx_list[idx])
            idx += 1
        else:
            output_str += input_str[i]
    return output_str
```

I wonder if there is any shorter and faster way than the concatenation that I have used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One concise approach uses `re.sub` with a callback function:

```py
input_str = 'The substring of "python" from index @ to index @ inclusive is "tho"'
idx_list = [2, 4]
output_str = re.sub(r'\bindex @', lambda m: str(idx_list.pop(0)), input_str)
print(output_str)

# The substring of "python" from 2 to 4 inclusive is "tho"
```

The idea here is that every time a match of `index @` is found, we replace with the first entry in the list of indices.  We also then pop that first index, so that it doesn't get used again.

Comment: When I change `r'\bindex @'` to `r'\b @'`, it doesn't work. I want to only swap `@` for the list elements and keep the word index.

Comment: @plpm You can use `r'\@'`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use formatted strings?
It would look like this:

```
idx_list = [2,4]
input_str = f'The substring of "python" from index {idx_list[0]} to index {idx_list[1]} inclusive is "tho"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically recreating str.format() using a slightly different format string. see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method

If you just want to fix the format to exactly match how python already does the task you're doing, just replace '@' with '{}'

```
input_str = 'The substring of "python" from index @ to index @ inclusive is "tho"'
idx_list = [2, 4]
print(input_str.replace('@', '{}').format(*idx_list))
```

But if the original string is really big, you may not want to add the replace step. Since we want to favor iterators in that case, write a generator to go through the string and yield its characters, except replace '@' with the next argument in your idx_list.

```
# my first draft is a bit clunky
def replace_char(input_str, idx_list):
    def replace(s, args):
        for char in s:
            if char == '@':
                yield str(next(args))
            else:
                yield char
    return ''.join(replace(input_str, iter(idx_list)))

input_str = 'The substring of "python" from index @ to index @ inclusive is "tho"'
idx_list = [2, 4]
print(replace_char(input_str, idx_list))
```

This is not really any different from your original code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```py
def replace_char(input_str: str, min_index: int, max_index: int) -> str:
    return input_str[:min_index] + '@' * (max_index - min_index) + input_str[max_index:]

input_str = 'The substring of "python" from index @ to index @ inclusive is "tho"'

output_str = replace_char(input_str, 2, 4)
print(output_str)

# Th@@substring of "python" from index @ to index @ inclusive is "tho"  # 'Th@@substring of "python" from index @ to index @ inclusive is "tho"'
```